# Есть ли у apache maven команда чтобы не собирать полность вебархив war, но помещать в распакованую папку только измененные классы?

Tags: java, maven

Идея следующая:
Есть мавен-проект, при смене класса нужно пересобирать архив. Это процедура достаточно длительная, около 20 секунд командой mvn package.
Есть ли другая команда которая говорит мавену заменять в результирующей папке только те классы и ресурсы, которые поменялись в проекте(исходниках)?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы система сборки (в Вашем случае Maven) имела возможность собирать только изменения, она должна иметь в своём составе также и некую систему контроля версий, чего в Maven нет. Соответственно, исключительно средствами Maven этого сделать нельзя. Зато система контроля версий есть в большинстве сред разработки.

Вы можете использовать, например, IntelliJ Idea, которая распознает файлы конфигурации проекта (pom.xml) и создаёт на их основе свои артефакты. Т.е., вы описали в pom.xml свой war, Idea создаёт на его основе артефакт, и даёт возможность осуществлять сборку артефакта средствами среды разработки, а не средствами Maven. При этом Idea, имея встроенную систему контроля версий, использует её при сборке артефакта, и осуществляет сборку только изменённых классов и файлов, что происходит очень быстро. Ограничение - war должен быть exploded, т.е. собираться в папку, а не в архив.

Каждый раз при изменении конфигурации Maven в pom.xml, Idea это увидит и предложит обновить свои артефакты, за счёт чего отпадает необходимость настраивать конфигурацию в двух местах.

Comment: Но можно ведь использовать время последнего изменения файла и сверять его с итоговым в папке exploded, если файл поменялся - то обносить, если нет - не трогать

Comment: Да можно, но у какого из сотен/тысяч файлов проверять время последнего изменения перед сборкой? Если проходить по всем файлам, то это сравнимо со временем сборки проекта целиком. Вместо этого надо где-то отслеживать факты изменения каждого файла, и вести список изменённых файлов (индекс?), чтобы в момент сборки сразу знать, что собирать, а что - нет. А это уже полпути к системе контроля версий или среде разработки. Maven не является ни тем ни другим.

Answer (score 0):

Для ускорения процесса сборки можете попробовать Hotswap техники (точнее, так даже собирать проект каждый раз не придется), которые подменяют классы на лету. Например, [DCEVM](https://dcevm.github.io/) . DCEVM подменяет обычные java классы, но не работает с контекстом, т.е. со Spring и Hibernate это не работает. Если нужно работать с контекстом к DCEVM нужно добавить [hotswap-agent](https://github.com/HotswapProjects/HotswapAgent). Правда, все эти проекты делаются руками энтузиастов, так что для продакшена сборки данной jvm не покатят.

Самым стабильным и мощным решением в этой области является JRebel, но он платный (сильно платный).

И да - 20 секунд, как я вам завидую :-)

Comment: спасибо :) прочитал про jrebel, это конечно хорошо, но для старта пока есть проблема только обновлять мавеном вручную файлики которые изменились. Сейчас выполняю mvn package хотя архив даже не трогаю, локкально проставленны ссылки в томкате, которые смотрят в папки <имя_модуля>/target/<имя_модуля> всех проектов.